# How to increase the vertical height and add space between contents in div scroll in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to add space between each div and the circle should show in full size.

HTML :

```
<body>
<h1 class="page-header">Horizontal Scroll for questions</h1>
<div class="container-fluid" style="overflow-x:scroll;white-space: nowrap;overflow-y:hidden ;">

    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>2</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>3</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>4</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>5</h6>

    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>5</h6>

    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6>5</h6>

    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 c">
        <h6> 5</h6>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

CSS :

```
.col-sm-3{display: inline-block;width:auto;}

.c {

 color: #64cbcd;
 font-size: 11px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border-color: blue;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #002525; // JUST ADD THIS LINE AND MODIFY YOUR     COLOR
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Here is the JS Fiddle of my demo : http://jsfiddle.net/arunslb123/g87Lkpxo/

What I'm trying to achieve is as below :

[image: Output image]

Is there any horizontal scroll plugin to do this?

Comment: As per your image I think you're looking for a slider: http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/basic.html

you can customize it accordingly.

Comment: just take a look at this..... http://jsfiddle.net/meeneshjain/g87Lkpxo/3/

Comment: Does **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/x22bdqv3/)** work for you? I will post it as answer and explain what I have updated if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @MeeneshJain Thanks!  It works.

Comment: @TahirAhmed ya it helps. please do.

Answer (score 1):

When I change the `display` property to `inline-block` and give it `margin-left` it gives me the spaces.

http://jsfiddle.net/g87Lkpxo/1/

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `display: table-cell` and you can add more space between circle with `margin-left` or `margin-right`

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your fiddle to look like this: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x22bdqv3/)**.

Here is what has changed:

- Inline styles on `.container-fluid` element were moved to CSS.
- Applied these changes to `.container-fluid` element: `height: 44px;` and `padding-top: 4px;`.
- Applied these changes to `.c` element: `display: inline-block;`, `margin-left: 10px;`, `padding-left: 10px;` and `padding-bottom: 10px;`.
- Added a new rule for `h6` elements: `h6 { margin-left: -10px; }`.

***Snippet:***

```css
.container-fluid {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 44px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
.col-sm-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:auto;
}
.c {
    color: #64cbcd;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #002525;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h6 {
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="page-header">Horizontal Scroll for questions</h1>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
         <h6>2</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
         <h6>3</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
         <h6>4</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
         <h6>5</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
         <h6>5</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
         <h6>5</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
         <h6> 5</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.